# Integrating existing C code to Go. Convert unsigned char poiner result to []byte

Tags: go, cgo

Here is a simple example:

```
package main

//#include <stdio.h>
//#include <strings.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>
/*
typedef struct {
    unsigned char *data;
    unsigned int data_len;
} Result;

Result *foo() {
    Result *r = malloc(sizeof(Result));

    r->data = (unsigned char *)malloc(10);
    r->data_len = 10;

    memset(r->data, 0, 10);

    r->data = (unsigned char *)strdup("xxx123");
    r->data_len = 6;

    return r;
}
*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    // "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    result := C.foo()

    fmt.Printf("%v, %v, %v\n", result.data, string(*(result.data)), result.data_len)
}
```

As a result i've got something like this

```
0x203970, x, 6
```

pointer to `data`, first character of `data` and the size. But how can i get the actual `data` value, preferably as a []byte type to use it in go code?
In other words - how to convert `unsigned char *` to `[]byte`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with [`unsafe.Pointer`](http://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer) and [`C.GoStringN`](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/):

```
data := (*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(result.data))
data_len := C.int(result.data_len)

fmt.Println(C.GoStringN(data, data_len))
```

And the most simple way:

```
data := (*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(result.data))
fmt.Println(C.GoString(data))
```

Comment: Won't that `unsafe.Sizeof` call just return the size of the pointer rather than the length of the array it points to?

Comment: One more question. In the real porgram *data is a binary data, not the string. Is it ok cast it to char* and convert with a GoString?

Comment: @JamesHenstridge, yeah, you're right. I suppose it's just magically worked for me in this example. I'll remove it from the answer.

Comment: @tacobot, there is a `func C.GoBytes(unsafe.Pointer, C.int) []byte` for that.